# What is this data? Resource Hacker

Tags: windows-7, debug, hexdump, decompile

I'm new to using Resource Hacker to alter *.EXE and *.DLL files and I need help understanding all the data it provides when "opening" these files.

More specifically, using Res Hacker, I opened **ntoskrnl.exe** which is located in C:\Windows\System32\ and I pressed **"PREFETCHWLIST : 0"** file in the **"RCData"** folder. This is what Res Hacker displayed:

[image: (Image)]

What does all this data represent? What type of data is displayed in each of the three columns? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First column is the address in memory.
Second column is the raw dump of the byte data
Third is that same data displayed decoded using defaults. 
see here http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Comment: Thanks, archae0pteryx. (I upvoted your answer but it's not yet visible.) Is it possible to use the data dump to decompile the program (**ntoskrnl.exe**)?

Comment: @banana I'm not sure. That's a bit outta my depth... =) I would start here if i was going at this sort of thing...    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146192/general-purpose-utility-or-library-for-compiling-decompiling-binary-data-files

Comment: Once again, thanks. I'll make sure to check that question.